# Is it possible to get FFMPEG to fix files that aren't reporting basic metadata in Windows file details?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, metadata

I am using the Folder.GetDetailsOf method of the Windows FileSystemObject to extract basic information (duration, frame width, frame height, etc.) from various video files on my computer. That method accesses the same information you will find by using Windows Explorer, choosing a file and opening its properties and then selecting "Details".

Generally, MP4 files are not a problem, but every once in a while I encounter one where that metadata is not presented there. There never appears to be anything else amiss with these files. Usually, running FFMPEG and using the options to just copy the codecs will correct the problem, but sometimes it doesn't.

When that happens my current solution is to use Handbrake to transcode the file, which will work, but that's quite a PITA when all I want is for FFMPEG to do what it should in the first place.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: I believe that the files weren't properly closed when they were created (by encoding software, I assume). Typically when I see this, it's because I killed off the encoding software before it was done writing the file. Usually the files still play, but players aren't able to tell me such things as resolution, or duration. You likely could re-encode the files with FFMPEG or other encoders to get those details back, but I'd suggest you solve the issue where it starts, if that's an option for you.

Comment: It's possible that you have identified the cause, but I can't confirm that because I didn't perform the original encoding, so unfortunately that's not an option. Can you suggest the FFMPEG options that I would use to correct the issue without downgrading the content quality or do I need to analyze each file and set the options to mirror the source (I think I remember a similar question where that was unfortunately the answer)?

Comment: I'm not exactly an expert with FFMPEG so I'm not entirely sure if this will work or not, but try:

 ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err -i video.mkv -c copy video_fixed.mkv

I "believe" this will not have to completely re-encode your files, keeping the original quality. I'm pretty sure this WELL have to completely re-analyze the file though, as it will also skip over typically playback errors, such as missing bad/chunks of the source media.

Comment: Ah, alas, this setting didn't have any effect beyond informing me that the "codec frame size is not set", but I do truly I appreciate your efforts on my behalf.

Comment: Would you be able to provide the complete output from FFMPEG for the last "codec frame size is not set" error? I've looked around the web for the the message, and it seems to only be relating to AAC audio. Some things I've read suggest possible issues with the build of FFMPEG (E.G. compiled without AAC support libraries or others). But, again, I could be completely off base. Do your source files contain AAC audio? Are you able to share one of the effected files to allow me to try a few things against it?

Comment: Certainly, I have no problem with either request. How should I proceed? I am new to this site, but I looked and didn't see a PM option.

Comment: Can you host the file on your Google drive or similar and share a link. Stack exchange is mostly against the idea of private messaging and thus doesn't provide any means for users to connect with other directly.

Comment: I have done so, but in the process I located a little egg on my face, but maybe it doesn't matter. I was unaware that my original source file was actually an AVI, so I have posted it here [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uug2zom9y3j8fc8/CJazz.avi?dl=0). I reran FFMPEG and determined that it also encountered the same error. I could post the log and the original codec information, but I expect that will become evident quickly once you look at the file.

Comment: So was this one of your problem files? I could really see too much wrong with it in my testing. the metadata appears in file explorer (file properties) with no issue. I ran it against FFMPEG using:

ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err -i input.avi -c copy video_fixed.avi

All I could detect was that stream 0 (xvid stream) didn't have timestamps, but that was only a warning, it was able to copy the file into the destination in mere seconds (no transcoding), both the source and destination file played back without any issues in all players I attempted.

Comment: Yes, to all your question and observations. But now go look at the Windows file explorer detailed properties of your new MP4 file and see that none of that metadata is presented there (length, frame height, etc.). This is the crux of my question and issue. That information is available in the original AVI file and is normally available in MP4 files processed by FFMPEG, but not in this case. I know that it is not a primary or essential function of FFMPEG to handle writing this information, but it is essential to my needs.

Comment: so when you generated the secondary output from FFMPEG, is that an MP4 or avi, when I tested i generated an AVI from the source (AVI) and I get all those same details in file properties in windows. maybe FFMPEG strips them if you convert o MP4 from AVI?

Copy the EXACT ffmpeg cmd you use, if you can.

Comment: Yes, I am converting into MP4 as that is the entire reason I am going through the process at all. Here is a simple version of the command line that will demonstrate the problem:

ffmpeg.exe -i %1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy "%~dp1%~n1.mp4"